# Unable to load large .DBF file in SSIS

Tags: ssis, oledb, foxpro, dbf

I have received few files(.DBF) from client. Each files is of different size (ranging from 40 Kb to 2.2 Gb)
I am using MS VS Foxpro driver..Provider connection manager.
When I connect (to retrieve tables) to the folder where all there files are stored. In Table/View dropdown, I see all tables except the one with size > 2Gb.

I am able to reproduce this scenario in other systems as well.
Suppose, if the DBF file size is 1.5 Gb, the table shows up in dropdown.

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a sizing limit on VFP perhaps? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3edd0290-2e63-49f2-8f69-e590737ea96f/limitations-of-a-foxpro-database That or the 32bit driver doesn't handle it and you need to use 64 bit?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum size for a Visual FoxPro table or almost anything else is 2GB. So I would imagine that is your problem. A 64 bit driver will make no difference. I'm not sure how the client is creating files > 2GB either, unless they're using something other than Fox.

Comment: That's why I suggested to the user to look into Sybase Advantage Server which recognizes/works with VFP tables (and other .dbf) files and can handle over the 2 gig limit AND is not limited to the 255 fields per record.

Comment: But doesn't support database container stuff like stored procedures and triggers, IIRC. Which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: That may be true, but the poster was looking to upgrade to another server and just appeared to need to READ the data... but you DO have a good point.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into SyBase Advantage Local Server.  Sybase adapated there database to handle similar format of VFP and can read them directly and exceed the 2 gig file limit of 32-bit based applications.  I've been using for some time having converted another system from VFP OleDB.  Personally, I'm using C# with Sybase's Data Provider to connect to and read data.  From that, you could probably get to what you are looking for.

[Link for Sybase Local Server](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver/local-server)

It's royalty-free for local server and 2-concurrent-users for development/testing.

Comment: thanks for feedback DRapp.  I want to get more familiar with what you listed. Basically, you imported VFP Files into Advantage Local server first? and then use the imported data for downstream/required functionality. Please advice.

Comment: @JasonM, actually no on going to Advantage... Advantage can read VFP tables natively just like a normal VFP OleDb provider.  Just point to the physical path where the tables are located and select, insert, update, delete as needed.  But that should allow you to at least connect and SEE the data to do with as you need.

Comment: @DApp Thanks for your feedback earlier. I was able to load the file.Here is What I did 1) Installed [Advantage Data Architect] and [Advantage configuration utility] 2) Imported the DBF File(>2Gb) into [Advantage Data Architect] through [Import Data] 3) Accessing the Initial Catalog (Advantage Database) from SSIS Connection Manager and pointing to the table in dropdown(OLEDB Source). I am able to see the imported data now .Is there a way I can import this DBF file into SSIs directly without these many steps and manual inventions ?

Comment: @JasonM, Not directly that I can think of, unless you do an export from Advantage to some CSV format output, then do a bulk import to the main database.  You might want to try sampling in small chunks for proof of concept such as 1,000 records from the table.