# Update dBase III DBF file which has 1100 columns in c#

Tags: c#, oledb, dbase

How to Update dBase III DBF file which has 1100 columns in c# ? I tried "Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0" and "vfpoledb" providers but they are not able to update. I read that there a  255 columns limit with oledb. But even when I try to update a single column, an exception "Query too complex" is thrown. I am able to read data from this DBF though, if I limit the columns in select query. Is there any way, I can update this DBF in c# ?

Comment: I would expect `System.Data.Odbc` to be more native to formats of that era. But still, it's an old format.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873198/unable-to-load-large-dbf-file-in-ssis) regarding SyBase Advantage Local Server.  It allows reading VFP (dBASE) style .DBF files but also allows for files larger than the 2 gig limit and 255 columns.  It has its own "Provider" you can download and run with.  It's VERY similar with the OleDb providers (as they are all based on interface objects such as ICommand, IConnection, IDataAdapter, IParameter, etc)